# the GPU-enabled version of the Ops Agent, version 2.25.1+pre.gpu.1

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ops-agent

I followed the instruction on [install ops agent](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/monitor-gpus#review-metrics-dashboard)

but I cannot find how to correctly run the following cmd

```
sudo bash add-google-cloud-ops-agent-repo.sh --also-install \
  --version=MAJOR_VERSION.*.*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to replace the `MAJOR_VERSION.*.*` with the [specific version](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/solutions/agents/ops-agent/installation#install-specific-version) that you would like to install

However, for GPU enabled Instances, there is a specific respository and installation of the GPU-enabled version of the Ops Agent. Do note that this feature is still in preview.

You can install the [GPU-enabled version](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/monitor-gpus#install-ops-agent) of the Ops Agent by running the following command:

```
curl -sSO https://dl.google.com/cloudagents/add-google-cloud-ops-agent-repo.sh
sudo REPO_SUFFIX=20230214-1.1.1 bash add-google-cloud-ops-agent-repo.sh --also-install
```

Comment: thanks for you input, but i tried that already
udo bash add-google-cloud-ops-agent-repo.sh --also-install --version=2.25.1+pre.gpu.1
[2023-03-01T19:33:22+0000] The agent version [2.25.1+pre.gpu.1] is not allowed. Expected values: [latest],
or anything in the format of [MAJOR_VERSION.MINOR_VERSION.PATCH_VERSION] or [MAJOR_VERSION.*.*].

Comment: ``` 
~$ rm add-google-cloud-ops-agent-repo.sh ~$ curl -sSO dl.google.com/cloudagents/add-google-cloud-ops-agent-repo.sh ~$ sudo REPO_SUFFIX=20230214-1.1.1 bash add-google-cloud-ops-agent-repo.sh --also-install --version=2.25.1+pre.gpu.1 [2023-03-01T20:32:05+0000] The agent version [2.25.1+pre.gpu.1] is not allowed. Expected values: [latest], or anything in the format of [MAJOR_VERSION.MINOR_VERSION.PATCH_VERSION] or [MAJOR_VERSION.*.*].
```

Comment: 2.25.1+pre.gpu.1 is the latest available version for the GPU enabled Ops Agent.
You can omit the --version flag or set it as --version=latest.

Do note that the feature is still on preview and this particular version "2.25.1+pre.gpu.1" is still unsupported for the --version flag

Comment: Thanks in the end I had to install the agent and re-install it using the second set of CMD